# Django: ModelAdmin Class Won't Change Admin Page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm doing the Django 1.8 tutorial right now. The part I am having trouble with right now is customizing the admin form. Created a ModelAdmin class, which is supposed to change the order of the forms on the admin page so that the date published appears before question text.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['pub_date', 'question_text']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

But, every form on the admin page is still in the original order. The question text is still coming before date published. What is going wrong? I have searched google and stackoverflow to no avail. The problem seems to be too basic, so no one else seems to have posted about it before.

Edit: Out of nowhere, the code above started working. I have no idea what's going on. The problem might have been unrelated to my python code.

Answer (score 0):

set `model` and `form` attributes of `QuestionAdmin`:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['pub_date', 'question_text']

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Question
    form = QuestionForm

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Comment: Insert `from django import forms` line in head of your admin.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way (from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets))

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('pub_date', 'question_text',)
        }),
    )

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```